# Why would I get integer expression expected?

Tags: bash, shell-script, test

So, I'm trying to create a menu system in bash as a learning experience. I'm sure there are countless ways, and even "better" ways to do this, but what I've got is something like this...

```
echo "
2nd Menu
********
1) command
2) command
M) Main menu
X) Exit program
"
read -p "Choose option >" opt
if [ "$opt" -eq 1 ]; then
    commands
elif [ "$opt" -eq 2 ]; then
    commands
elif [[ "$opt" = [m,M] ]]; then
    main #calls the function main()
elif [[ "$opt" = [x,X] ]]; then
    exit
else
    echo "Invalid option"
    main
fi
```

The script works for every option except the "X) Exit program".
When I run "X" or "x" I get this error...

```
./acct-mgr.sh: line 10: [: x: integer expression expected
./acct-mgr.sh: line 12: [: x: integer expression expected
Invalid option
```

This is baffling me! I'm pretty sure I'm using the correct comparison operator for each data type (-eq for integers and = for strings), coupled with the fact that EVERY option works EXCEPT that "x".

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

P.S. - Alternative ways of accomplishing the desired result is greatly appreciated, but even then I would like to know why this isn't working for my edification. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you enter M/m or X/x, you're comparing a non-number to a number using `-eq`, and that is causing the failure.  If you want `$opt` to be a string sometimes, treat it as a string all of the time:

```
...
if [ "$opt" = "1" ]; then
    commands
elif [ "$opt" = "2" ]; then
    commands
...
```

Comment: That totally makes sense! Thanks, Andy!
I still don't understand why M/m worked and X/x failed with the error though? Is it just a quirk of the system?

Comment: I don't see how M/m would have worked, unless at some point you checked those cases before 1/2.

Comment: That must be what's happening. Regardless, your solution worked perfectly! Cheers :)

Answer (score 6):

As an addition to what [@Andy already said](/a/3916616), note that

```
[[ "$opt" = [m,M] ]]
```

matches on `m`, `,` and `M`. If you wanted to match on `m` and `M` only, that would be

```
[[ "$opt" = [mM] ]]
```

Here, I'd use a standard `case` construct though:

```
case $opt in
  (1)   commands;;
  (2)   commands;;
  (m|M) main;;
  (x|X) exit;;
  (*)   echo >&2 "Invalid option"; main
esac
```

Also note that the behaviour of `read` depends on the current value of `$IFS`. If you wanted to read one line from the user, you'd use:

```
IFS= read -r opt
```

To read one character:

```
IFS= read -rn1 opt
```

To read one *word* (read one line, but ignore the leading space and tabs and anything but the first word):

```
IFS=$' \t' read -r opt ignored
```

Or to allow the use to include space or tabs in the *word* by prefixing with backslash:

```
IFS=$' \t' read opt ignored
```

Comment: Great information, Stephane! Thanks for the insight and contribution to this thread!